# Best way to let 2 servers communicate (with PHP) avoiding IP Spoofing?

Tags: php, session-management, ip-spoofing

Let's say I have my ServerB that accept any request and it checks the PHPSESSID and compares the IP saved into the session (thanks to session values) with the IP that made the HTTP request. The IP saved into the Session is the IP of a successfully authenticated client stored previously.  If the IP it's different, request gets blocked. Now Assuming that I have a ServerA, which it's able to send requests to ServerB and ServerB have whitelisted the IP of ServerA, is possible for a third user spoof and clone the IP of  ServerA in order to make valid the request (because authorized) even if it shouldn't be? If yes how can change my system in order to make it secure in this aspect?

EDIT:
Security check has changed as follows:
I removed the IP check and I introduced a hash that it's saved in a session variable when a user logs in, then it will be printed by the page. Next, when a user tries to request with its PHPSESSID, the script (on serverB) verifies the correspondence of the hash variable given in input with hash saved into the session at the login time. If this check doesn't pass, the session gets destroyed. Else my serverA with the PHPSESSID and the right hash could perform my request. It's the best I can think to reach the goal in this case, what do you think about this other solution?

Comment: Whether or not it's possible, you shouldn't rely on IP addresses for authentication.

Comment: @multithr3at3d check the IP address it's just another layer of security in my opinion. Anyway, what do you suggest?

Comment: It's possible for a user to spoof his IP address, to make a request to the server appear as if it's coming from an IP other than his own.  But, he wouldn't receive a response from the server, because the server would send the response back to the spoofed IP.

Comment: @Virgula I agree that whitelisting the server in firewall rules is a good idea, but conventional authentication over a secure channel is what should be relied on.

Comment: so what could be a solution to check securely if the request is sent by my authorized server or not?

Comment: You should rely on the session id to keep track of authenticated users.  This is normally how web applications maintain state.  To impersonate Server B, the 'third user' would have to access the session id that your application assigned to Server B, which is not simple to do.  Relying on the IP address is not recommended because multiple users could have the same IP address, a user's IP address can change, etc.

Comment: @mti2935 When a user logs in, I set a SESSION boolean variable to true, so I can check if the user is effectively authorized before to check the IP too (p.s: don't matter if the IP changes, the user will be notified to re-login.) This is just an optional layer of security that I want.
Anyway, I could not understand how session_id could work to let communicate ServerA and ServerB securely. Any practical example could help here.

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea.  You may want to store the user id in the session variable, so that your applications knows *which* user is logged in.  Here is a practical example:  https://johnmorrisonline.com/build-php-login-form-using-sessions/

Comment: @mti2935 thanks for the link, but I already used basic sessions checks like that. Anyway, I removed the IP check and I introduced a hash that it's saved in a session variable when a user logs in, then it will be printed by the page. Next, when a user tries to request with its PHPSESSID, the script verifies the correspondence of the hash variable given in input with hash saved into the session at the login time. If this check doesn't pass, the session gets destroyed. Now my serverB with the PHPSESSID and the right hash could perform my request. Hoping this solution it's secure like before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is IP whitelisting for webpage access secure enough?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177931/is-ip-whitelisting-for-webpage-access-secure-enough)

Comment: @ximaera what does that other question means? we're talking about the best method to let 2 servers communicate avoiding the IP security check because obsolete

Comment: You may want to either edit the question title or to ask a different question since that one has gone too far from the original problem.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to authenticate each message with a message authentication code like HMAC-SHA256, if the two peers can share a secret, or to sign it with a signature scheme like Ed25519, if the two peers can share a public key and you want third-party verifiability of the messages as an audit trail.