# Using IP for one request (one time) protection

Tags: authentication, ip, authorization

I have an endpoint that accepts data as signed PASETO tokens. It has one problem - if someone "cracks" the TLS encryption or this signed token leaks then everyone can use it as long as the token isn't expired (signed token has a lifetime of up to 15 seconds). I don't want to use e.g. signed-then-encrypted tokens with e.g. ECDH key exchange because it's hard to handle (many logic, integrating used symmetric key with signed token) and less efficent.
In the token payload I also use TOTP, but what if I also add the request source IP to token payload? Then even if the token is stolen then the hacker can use it only from a spoofed IP and the response will be sent to the original request source.

So is this IP "protection" good for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is this IP "protection" good for this scenario?

No.

1. It seems to be an XY problem. Your statement *"data as signed PASETO tokens"* means that you want to encrypt and sign data independent on TLS. This is not bad itself. But using PASETO for this is  wrong. The purpose of PASETO is to offer encryption and signature for *authentication tokens*, not for arbitrary data. For data encryption and signature there are many other standard secure approaches.
2. If you don't trust TLS, then you don't trust modern cryptography that in particular is also used in PASETO. By not trusting TLS and trusting PASETO you contradict to yourself.
3. Relying on client IP is not secure, because it is up to provider to assign IPs, and client IP can change dynamically. Thus you will prohibit access to the properly authenticated users.
4. Relying on client IP is not secure, because client can switch between different WIFI networks dynamically, e.g. when moving by a car, train or public transport. Thus you will prohibit access to the properly authenticated users.
5. Relying on client IP is not secure, because if the attacker is behind a proxy of some big company, you will not distinguish the attacker from the other users of this company based on IP.
6. If you believe TLS can be cracked, then you should suppose that also the authentication request can be intercepted and the attacker will obtain the user credentials. Then the attacker does not need your token. Instead, the attacker will send an authentication request with these credentials to your authentication service and will obtain a valid token directly. If you add an IP to the token, this will be the IP of the attacker. Thus adding an IP does not add any security.

Comment: I know that client IP can be changed dynamically, but it's basic API request. If client switch beetwen differents WiFi while request, it also should be unfinished. That's it what I mean, this IP "authorization" is only for one request and nothing more. What's more, it's backchannel communication what means that it's beetwen client machine and server. I trust to TLS, but my app requires really high security, hence my doubts and question. Therefore, do you still think my idea isnt enough good?

Comment: You have not said anything about the most important part, the 1st one. I still see your approach as an XY problem. You are applying wrong tools for your goal. Why do you want overhead of PASETO instead of any standard encryption and instead of any standard signing algorithms?

Comment: I don't want use PASETO instead of any standard encryption, but for signing with Ed25519. Why? Because I have to use claims like audience, issuer and subject, and often paseto footer and implicit assertion is very helpful for me.

Comment: ChaCha20 is widely used in TLS 1.3. PASETO uses it, too. TLS 1.3 uses elliptic curve 25519. PASETO uses it, too. You say *"if someone "cracks" the TLS encryption..."*. Then if someone cracks ChaCha20, it will be cracked not only for TLS, but obviously for all cases where it is used including PASETO. If someone cracks cryptography based on the elliptic curve 25519, obviously it will be cracked not only for TLS, but also for PASETO. You contradict to yourself when you attempt to secure cracked TLS by using cracked PASETO.

Comment: I would suppose that you don't understand the cryptography well and that you expect that *adding more magic* will add more security. Think of the [Kerkoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle). Simply making algorithm more obscure or more complicated does not add any security.

Comment: *"... Ed25519. Why? Because I have to use claims like..."* If you don't want to use standards like OAuth2 and prefer to implement your own approach, then you are free to use any structure you need. You can add any fields to the data that you sign. I don't see any reason to use PASETO just because it defines some fields that you need.

Comment: TLS 1.3 isn't widely used, in Windows it's named as experimental. What's more, TLS encrypt/sign data only while transport, it's not end to end. Going back to the question, will this IP verification make any sense?

Comment: Sure, TLS does not encrypt end to end. That's why I said that the data encryption on application level is fine. But if you believe TLS can be cracked, it means also PASETO can be cracked at the same time. Besides, 99% of web server choose non-RSA handshake, where as PASETO still uses RSA.

Comment: To the IP: Token cannot be stolen by cracking TLS. If your server side is protected enough, token can only be stolen on the client side. If the attacker can steal the token on the client device, then the attacker can also send requests from the client device. This means checking the IP is useless.

Comment: I have updated the answer. See the point 6.

Comment: Ok, assume that token can be stolen on the client device, so as you mentioned, attacker can also send request from the client device. But it doesn't mean that attacker also got access to ed25519 private key which is e.g. stored in HSM. So the attacker can send requests only with generated tokens via client app (and the token has max 10s lifetime). I guess it makes sense now. What do you think?

Comment: If the token is stolen on the client device, it means the application (Java Script or the App) is compromised. Means, the malicious code working within your application has access to everything you application can access, including HSM. 10s lifetime can be sufficient for the attacker. The attacker would not do that manually. It would be an automated process. Means, the token would be used as soon as it was retrieved. You should expect within less than 1s.

Answer (score 1):

> if someone "cracks" the TLS encryption

Then your application would be unlikely to be among the first ones to be hacked. Probably not among the first thousands if that doesn't happen to be e.g. a cryptocurrency exchange.

> what if I also add the request source IP to token payload? Then even if the token is stolen then the hacker can use it only from a spoofed IP

Even establishing a TCP connection from a spoofed IP address is [theoretically possible but practically infeasible](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/177945/168418). Establishing a **TLS session** on top of that TCP connection should be considered impossible.

Yet, IP address filtering is circumventable with [BGP hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP_hijacking). This is a rare, expensive and very complicated technique, however, if "cracking" the contemporary TLS v1.2-v1.3 encryption is within your [threat model](https://owasp.org/www-community/Threat_Modeling_Process#ranking-of-threats), BGP hijacking surely should be as well.

Though I doubt either of these should be.

Note that there are [other potential sources](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/177945/168418) of issues with IP-based filtering such as e.g. XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: So do you think that it's pretty good as additional layer of authentication? (I have TOTP and signing also). Could you please consider another answer and my comment, please?